# C++17 is_integral trait implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, template-meta-programming, c++17, sfinae

This is a C++17 `is_integral` trait implementation.

Most implementations exhaust all integral types:

- `bool`
- `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`
- `[unsigned] short`
- `[unsigned] [long [long]] int`

However, it is possible that the implementation defines some [*extended signed integer types*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1) and [*extended unsigned integer types*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#2). One workaround is to exhaust all the implementations using `#ifdef`s, but this workaround is not theoretically (in the language lawyer's point of view) portable. For example, if Mickey Mouse just rolls out a brand-new standard-conforming extended integer type, such workarounds fail.

I theorized that for any type `T`, `is_integral<T>::value` is `true` if and only if it is convertible to `std::intmax_t` or `std::uintmax_t` via a **non-narrowing** *standard conversion sequence*. I tried to deploy this fact, enforcing the two restrictions respectively, by:

- using the so-called "uniform initialization" syntax (formally *list-initialization*) to prevent narrowing conversions; and
- using a dummy class (which I call a *generator* class) with a conversion operator to prevent user-defined conversion sequences.

I tested with the cases of standard integral types (expecting true,) standard floating point types (expecting false,) user-defined types convertible to some standard integral type (expecting false.) **All tests passed.**

Here is my code, within 40 lines.

```
// C++17 is_integral implementation
// which handles extended integer types
// in a portable way
// (without resorting to #ifdef chains)

#include <cinttypes> // for std::intmax_t, std::uintmax_t
#include <type_traits> // for std::is_same, std::bool_constant
                       // can be trivially defined manually, just lazy

namespace my_std {
    namespace detail {
        // Generator type to bypass user-defined conversions
        template <typename T>
        struct Generator {
            operator T();
        };
        // helper type to designate substitution failure
        struct Failed {};
        // check functions (exploit SFINAE)
        // uses brace syntax to prevent narrowing conversions
        template <typename T>
        auto check_signed(int) -> decltype(std::intmax_t{Generator<T>{}});
        template <typename T>
        auto check_signed(...) -> Failed;
        template <typename T>
        auto check_unsigned(int) -> decltype(std::uintmax_t{Generator<T>{}});
        template <typename T>
        auto check_unsigned(...) -> Failed;
        // function invoker trait
        template <typename T>
        struct Int_trait {
            static constexpr bool is_signed_int = !std::is_same_v<
                Failed, decltype(check_signed<T>(0))
            >;
            static constexpr bool is_unsigned_int = !std::is_same_v<
                Failed, decltype(check_unsigned<T>(0))
            >;
            static constexpr bool is_int = is_signed_int || is_unsigned_int;
        };
    }
    // "the" trait
    template <typename T>
    struct is_integral
        :std::bool_constant<detail::Int_trait<T>::is_int>
        { };
}
```

Any criticism or suggestion is highly appreciated!

<sub><joke>The absolute best implementation with maximum portability and simplicity and clarity that is guaranteed to work on all machines is:</sub>

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace my_std {
    template <typename T>
    struct is_integral
        :std::is_integral<T>
        { };
}
```

<sup></joke></sup>

Comment: I like your joke! More seriously, why would you "manually [replace] `intmax_t`s with `__int128_t`"? Doesn't it defeat you initial purpose to provide a platform-independent implementation? And doesn't it prove that another plat-form could as well provide a similar extension that your code wouldn't take into account? Besides, to comply with the standard, `std::is_integral_v<__int128_t>` should be false, because it is neither a standard integer type nor an extended integer type, but a language extension.

Comment: @papagaga Well... You are very helpful. I explained it too badly... The problem is, I am unable to find a single accessible implementation with a real extended integer type. And `__int128_t` was the closest I could find, although it is still not a real one. As a workaround, I faked `intmax_t` to test it with a (fake) one... I was appreciate if there is actually one I can test on ;-)

Comment: "I found that for any type `T`, `is_integral<T>::value` is true if and only if: it is convertible to `std::intmax_t` or `std::uintmax_t` via a non-narrowing standard conversion sequence." — This is true for the _standard_ integral types, but as you yourself realized, it's not true for the implementation-defined _extended_ integral types. For the situation with `__int128_t`, see [Is `__int128` integral?](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/28/is-int128-integral/).

Comment: @Quuxplusone I know `__int128_t` is not an integral type at all. Just have no nondirty way to test... I will delete that part anyway.

Comment: "I know `__int128_t` is not an integral type at all." — No, you *think* `__int128_t` is not an integral type at all. Both libc++ (in all modes) and libstdc++ (in `-std=gnu++XX` mode) disagree with you, though. See the blog post [Is `__int128` integral?](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/28/is-int128-integral/) for more details.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Sorry, I meant "I know the way I tested `__int128_t` (with gcc in an ordinary mode) is one in which `__int128_t` is not an integral type at all." I read you blog post and it seems to suggest that I can do this test in clang or in `-std=gnu++XX` gcc?

Comment: But [it says `false`.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tu22ltmjrrVi7fIX)

Comment: Here's side-by-side comparison of your `my_std::is_integral<__int128>` with `std::is_integral<__int128>`. https://godbolt.org/z/Ka9F6V I **really, really, highly recommend** just reading the blog post! It goes into great detail on what happens and why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tested with the cases of standard integral types (expecting true,) standard floating point types (expecting false,) user-defined types convertible to some standard integral type (expecting false.) **All tests passed.**

You should have tested with all the other kinds of types in C++. Reference types, pointer types, enum types, `nullptr_t`, `void`, pointer-to-member types, etc. etc.

Your `is_integral` incorrectly reports that `int&` is an integral type. ([Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/PUcV72))

It's not a hard fix, of course; but the code-review feedback is "Write more tests."

Comment: You're right. I will need more tests when writing template stuff. Or simply stop reinventing the wheel ... :P